# ASP.NET MVC debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, asp.net-mvc-2

I have trouble debugging ASP.NET MVC (1 & 2) in VS2008. Most often stepinto and stepover is just like hitting run. This also happens even if there is a breakpoint in the code on the next line. I've experienced this problem all along using MVC and others working in my team experience it as well.

Does anyone else have this problem? Is this a bug in VS2008 or is there a solution? Does the debugger work better with MVC when using VS2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what causes it (and it can be very sporadic), but I have experienced what you describe using VS2008. Never using VS2010 though, so that indicates to me that there have been some improvements made somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger works fine in VS2010 for me and at least 3 other colleagues of mine. I didn't use MVC in VS2008, so I can't comment on that.

Comment: The debugger normally works fine both in VS2008 and 2010. I'm only experience this problem when i am debugging my MVC application.

Comment: That's what I meant: I debugged my MVC applications in VS2010 just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had a problem like this with VS 2008. 
Check web.config file for if it has debug setting set to true. 
You can  also debug your application via IIS. Set IIS working directory to the folder with your project. 
Enter in browser http://localhost. Your start page should open, then you can attach with debuger to w3wp.exe process.

Comment: I've tried this solution and I think it works slightly better but not perfect.

Comment: @Marcus - Are there any other details that you could provide. Does it work ok if you debug on the same machine with the same login other projects?.

Comment: I haven't tried other projects, but other people in my team (other computers) also have the same problem.

Comment: @Marcus - I'm not sure if it might help but try to run VS as administrator. Maybe there are some issues with rights.

Comment: Running VS as administrator didnt help.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with VS in general. If you have the same issue with other projects there is only "ultimate" solution, complete reinstall.